# Plot a single column data with different scale on the horizontal axis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data.txt file that is only composed of one column of values.
Example:

```
1.10145
1.10293
1.10365
# ...
```

When I use

```
plot "data.txt" w linesp
```

I get a plot with the data of data.txt used for the vertical axis, and the scale of the horizontal axis is auto-generated (it's just a count of the data. 0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

The problem is that I want the horizontal axis to say 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ... instead.

How do I change the scale of the horizontal axis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot "data.txt" using ($0/10.):1 w linesp
```

should do the trick.